# Rails: Tunneling an octet stream from a REST API to the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, download

Our Rails app is acting as a middle man to another API. The user logs into the rails generated page, and all of the data for that page comes from a call to a REST API.

We've got a requirement now to take a CSV that gets streamed from the API, and tunnel it through so the user can download it.

The flow would basically be:

1. User clicks download link
2. Rails app receives request from the browser
3. Rails app sends and receives response from REST API
4. Rails sends the stream down to the browser

Is this possible?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, (is it more complex than it seems?)  but from what I see, yes.  You have 2 options, you can either fetch the stream via ajax once the user's page has loaded, or you can fetch the stream in the same controller action that's rendering the page being visited.  The former is potentially a more user-friendly option for very large files.